# Ordenar valores de um <li> por data C#

Tags: c#

É possível ordenar os valores de uma dropdown por dia? 
Existe um `order by` ou tem que se fazer realmente if's para tal?

Exemplo de código:

```
 <span class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-search dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="horas" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span id="newdisp">Nova disponibilidade</span><span class="caret" style="border-top:4px solid #FFF;"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="horas" onclick="newhour(event);">
        @{
            foreach (ScriptorContent horas in Model.Parts.Channel[0].Contents)
            {

                int empresa = (horas.Parts.titulo).LastIndexOf("- ");
                if (empresa > 0)
                {
                    string nome = (horas.Parts.titulo).Substring(empresa + 2);

                    if (nome == a.Parts.empresa[0].Parts.Name)
                    {
                        string horainicio = (horas.Parts.inicio).ToString("H:mm");
                        string horafim = (horas.Parts.fim).ToString("H:mm");
                        string data = (horas.Parts.inicio).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">@data @horainicio - @horafim</a></li>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: tu poderia usar um order by no teu foreach, ficaria algo do tipo `foreach (ScriptorContent horas in Model.Parts.Channel[0].Contents.OrderBy(a=>a.Campo))`, se der certo me avise que irei colocar como resposta

Comment: @PabloVargas está correto. Coloque como respostas, caso exista algum problema, você pode editar sua resposta.

Comment: Bem fiz de outra maneira. Fiz uma queryContents e depois dessa query, fiz o tal orderby, mas não foi com lambda expressions, fiz assim: Orderby("$$.titulo asc")
Obrigado pelas vossas respostas.

Answer (score 1):

uma solução para o seu problema, seria usar um `OrderBy` no seu `foreach`, ficando assim:

```
foreach (ScriptorContent horas in Model.Parts.Channel[0].Contents.OrderBy(a=>a.Campo))
```